# Add child to existing parent record in entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My relationship between the parent and child is that they are connected by an edge. It is similiar to a directed graph structure.

DAL:

```
    public void SaveResource(Resource resource)
    {
        context.AddToResources(resource); //Should also add children.
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public Resource GetResource(int resourceId)
    {
        var resource = (from r in context.Resources
                        .Include("ToEdges").Include("FromEdges")
                         where r.ResourceId == resourceId
                         select r).SingleOrDefault();

        return resource;
    }
```

Service:

```
    public void  AddChildResource(int parentResourceId, Resource childResource)
    {
        Resource parentResource = repository.GetResource(parentResourceId);

        ResourceEdge inEdge = new ResourceEdge();
        inEdge.ToResource = childResource;

        parentResource.ToEdges.Add(inEdge);

        repository.SaveResource(parentResource);
    }
```

Error: An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The existing object is in the Unchanged state. An object can only be added to the ObjectStateManager again if it is in the added state.

Image:

[image]

I have been told this is the sequence in submitting a child to an already existing parent:

**Get parent -> Attach Child to parent -> submit parent.**

That is the sequence I used. The code above is extracted from an ASP.NET MVC 2 application using the repository pattern.

EDMX file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <edmx:Edmx Version="2.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx">
      <!-- EF Runtime content -->
      <edmx:Runtime>
        <!-- SSDL content -->
        <edmx:StorageModels>
          <Schema Namespace="XDbModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2008" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">
            <EntityContainer Name="XDbModelStoreContainer">
              <EntitySet Name="Bundles" EntityType="XDbModel.Store.Bundles" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
              <EntitySet Name="CellProviders" EntityType="XDbModel.Store.CellProviders" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
              <EntitySet Name="Comments" EntityType="XDbModel.Store.Comments" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
              <EntitySet Name="LocationPoints" EntityType="XDbModel.Store.LocationPoints" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
              <EntitySet Name="Locations" EntityType="XDbModel.Store.Locations" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
              <EntitySet Name="Offers" EntityType="XDbModel.Store.Offers" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
              <EntitySet Name="PostBundleJunction" EntityType="XDbModel.Store.PostBundleJunction" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
              <EntitySet Name="PostMedia" EntityType="XDbModel.Store.PostMedia" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
              <EntitySet Name="Posts" EntityType="XDbModel.Store.Posts" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
              <EntitySet Name="ResourceEdges" EntityType="XDbModel.Store.ResourceEdges" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
              <EntitySet Name="ResourceNames" EntityType="XDbModel.Store.ResourceNames" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
              <EntitySet Name="Resources" EntityType="XDbModel.Store.Resources" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
              <EntitySet Name="sysdiagrams" EntityType="XDbModel.Store.sysdiagrams" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
              <EntitySet Name="Users" EntityType="XDbModel.Store.Users" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
              <EntitySet Name="Votes" EntityType="XDbModel.Store.Votes" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_Comments_Offers" Association="XDbModel.Store.FK_Comments_Offers">
                <End Role="Offers" EntitySet="Offers" />
                <End Role="Comments" EntitySet="Comments" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_Comments_Users" Association="XDbModel.Store.FK_Comments_Users">
                <End Role="Users" EntitySet="Users" />
                <End Role="Comments" EntitySet="Comments" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_LocationPoints_Locations" Association="XDbModel.Store.FK_LocationPoints_Locations">
                <End Role="Locations" EntitySet="Locations" />
                <End Role="LocationPoints" EntitySet="LocationPoints" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_PostBundleJunction_Bundles" Association="XDbModel.Store.FK_PostBundleJunction_Bundles">
                <End Role="Bundles" EntitySet="Bundles" />
                <End Role="PostBundleJunction" EntitySet="PostBundleJunction" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_PostBundleJunction_Posts" Association="XDbModel.Store.FK_PostBundleJunction_Posts">
                <End Role="Posts" EntitySet="Posts" />
                <End Role="PostBundleJunction" EntitySet="PostBundleJunction" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_Posts_Locations" Association="XDbModel.Store.FK_Posts_Locations">
                <End Role="Locations" EntitySet="Locations" />
                <End Role="Posts" EntitySet="Posts" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_Posts_ResourceNames" Association="XDbModel.Store.FK_Posts_ResourceNames">
                <End Role="ResourceNames" EntitySet="ResourceNames" />
                <End Role="Posts" EntitySet="Posts" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_Posts_Users" Association="XDbModel.Store.FK_Posts_Users">
                <End Role="Users" EntitySet="Users" />
                <End Role="Posts" EntitySet="Posts" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_ResourceEdges_Resources" Association="XDbModel.Store.FK_ResourceEdges_Resources">
                <End Role="Resources" EntitySet="Resources" />
                <End Role="ResourceEdges" EntitySet="ResourceEdges" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_ResourceEdges_Resources1" Association="XDbModel.Store.FK_ResourceEdges_Resources1">
                <End Role="Resources" EntitySet="Resources" />
                <End Role="ResourceEdges" EntitySet="ResourceEdges" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_ResourceNames_Resources" Association="XDbModel.Store.FK_ResourceNames_Resources">
                <End Role="Resources" EntitySet="Resources" />
                <End Role="ResourceNames" EntitySet="ResourceNames" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_Users_Locations" Association="XDbModel.Store.FK_Users_Locations">
                <End Role="Locations" EntitySet="Locations" />
                <End Role="Users" EntitySet="Users" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_Votes_Posts" Association="XDbModel.Store.FK_Votes_Posts">
                <End Role="Posts" EntitySet="Posts" />
                <End Role="Votes" EntitySet="Votes" />
              </AssociationSet>
            </EntityContainer>
            <EntityType Name="Bundles">
              <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="BundleId" />
              </Key>
              <Property Name="BundleId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="CellProviders">
              <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="CellProviderID" />
              </Key>
              <Property Name="CellProviderID" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="Comments">
              <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="CommentID" />
              </Key>
              <Property Name="CommentID" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="ParentPostID" Type="uniqueidentifier" />
              <Property Name="OfferPostID" Type="uniqueidentifier" />
              <Property Name="UserID" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="LocationPoints">
              <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="LocationPointId" />
              </Key>
              <Property Name="LocationPointId" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
              <Property Name="Latitude" Type="float" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="Longitude" Type="float" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="Altitude" Type="float" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="Count" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="LocationId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="Locations">
              <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="LocationId" />
              </Key>
              <Property Name="LocationId" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
              <Property Name="Address1" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="200" />
              <Property Name="Address2" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="200" />
              <Property Name="Address3" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="200" />
              <Property Name="State" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="200" />
              <Property Name="Country" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="200" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="Offers">
              <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="OfferID" />
              </Key>
              <Property Name="OfferID" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="NeedOffer" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="ProvisionOffer" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="PostBundleJunction">
              <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="BundleId" />
                <PropertyRef Name="PostId" />
              </Key>
              <Property Name="BundleId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="PostId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="PostMedia">
              <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="MediaId" />
              </Key>
              <Property Name="MediaId" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
              <Property Name="MediaExt" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="5" />
              <Property Name="PostId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="SynthId" Type="uniqueidentifier" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="Posts">
              <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="PostId" />
              </Key>
              <Property Name="PostId" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
              <Property Name="PosterID" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="BundleId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="LocationId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="Tags" Type="uniqueidentifier" />
              <Property Name="Quanitity" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="Description" Type="text" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="ResourceNameId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="Date" Type="datetime" Nullable="false" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="ResourceEdges">
              <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="EdgeId" />
              </Key>
              <Property Name="Rank" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="EdgeId" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
              <Property Name="ToResourceId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="FromResourrceId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="ResourceNames">
              <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="ResourceNameId" />
              </Key>
              <Property Name="ResourceNameId" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
              <Property Name="Name" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100" />
              <Property Name="ResourceId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="Resources">
              <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="ResourceId" />
              </Key>
              <Property Name="ResourceId" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
              <Property Name="Description" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="50" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="sysdiagrams">
              <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="diagram_id" />
              </Key>
              <Property Name="name" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="128" />
              <Property Name="principal_id" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="diagram_id" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
              <Property Name="version" Type="int" />
              <Property Name="definition" Type="varbinary(max)" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="Users">
              <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="UserID" />
              </Key>
              <Property Name="UserID" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="LocationId" Type="int" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="Votes">
              <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="VoteId" />
              </Key>
              <Property Name="VoteId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="VoterId" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="VoteContent" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
              <Property Name="PostId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
            </EntityType>
            <Association Name="FK_Comments_Offers">
              <End Role="Offers" Type="XDbModel.Store.Offers" Multiplicity="0..1" />
              <End Role="Comments" Type="XDbModel.Store.Comments" Multiplicity="*" />
              <ReferentialConstraint>
                <Principal Role="Offers">
                  <PropertyRef Name="OfferID" />
                </Principal>
                <Dependent Role="Comments">
                  <PropertyRef Name="OfferPostID" />
                </Dependent>
              </ReferentialConstraint>
            </Association>
            <Association Name="FK_Comments_Users">
              <End Role="Users" Type="XDbModel.Store.Users" Multiplicity="1">
                <OnDelete Action="Cascade" />
              </End>
              <End Role="Comments" Type="XDbModel.Store.Comments" Multiplicity="*" />
              <ReferentialConstraint>
                <Principal Role="Users">
                  <PropertyRef Name="UserID" />
                </Principal>
                <Dependent Role="Comments">
                  <PropertyRef Name="UserID" />
                </Dependent>
              </ReferentialConstraint>
            </Association>
            <Association Name="FK_LocationPoints_Locations">
              <End Role="Locations" Type="XDbModel.Store.Locations" Multiplicity="1">
                <OnDelete Action="Cascade" />
              </End>
              <End Role="LocationPoints" Type="XDbModel.Store.LocationPoints" Multiplicity="*" />
              <ReferentialConstraint>
                <Principal Role="Locations">
                  <PropertyRef Name="LocationId" />
                </Principal>
                <Dependent Role="LocationPoints">
                  <PropertyRef Name="LocationId" />
                </Dependent>
              </ReferentialConstraint>
            </Association>
            <Association Name="FK_PostBundleJunction_Bundles">
              <End Role="Bundles" Type="XDbModel.Store.Bundles" Multiplicity="1" />
              <End Role="PostBundleJunction" Type="XDbModel.Store.PostBundleJunction" Multiplicity="*" />
              <ReferentialConstraint>
                <Principal Role="Bundles">
                  <PropertyRef Name="BundleId" />
                </Principal>
                <Dependent Role="PostBundleJunction">
                  <PropertyRef Name="BundleId" />
                </Dependent>
              </ReferentialConstraint>
            </Association>
            <Association Name="FK_PostBundleJunction_Posts">
              <End Role="Posts" Type="XDbModel.Store.Posts" Multiplicity="1" />
              <End Role="PostBundleJunction" Type="XDbModel.Store.PostBundleJunction" Multiplicity="*" />
              <ReferentialConstraint>
                <Principal Role="Posts">
                  <PropertyRef Name="PostId" />
                </Principal>
                <Dependent Role="PostBundleJunction">
                  <PropertyRef Name="PostId" />
                </Dependent>
              </ReferentialConstraint>
            </Association>
            <Association Name="FK_Posts_Locations">
              <End Role="Locations" Type="XDbModel.Store.Locations" Multiplicity="1" />
              <End Role="Posts" Type="XDbModel.Store.Posts" Multiplicity="*" />
              <ReferentialConstraint>
                <Principal Role="Locations">
                  <PropertyRef Name="LocationId" />
                </Principal>
                <Dependent Role="Posts">
                  <PropertyRef Name="LocationId" />
                </Dependent>
              </ReferentialConstraint>
            </Association>
            <Association Name="FK_Posts_ResourceNames">
              <End Role="ResourceNames" Type="XDbModel.Store.ResourceNames" Multiplicity="1" />
              <End Role="Posts" Type="XDbModel.Store.Posts" Multiplicity="*" />
              <ReferentialConstraint>
                <Principal Role="ResourceNames">
                  <PropertyRef Name="ResourceNameId" />
                </Principal>
                <Dependent Role="Posts">
                  <PropertyRef Name="ResourceNameId" />
                </Dependent>
              </ReferentialConstraint>
            </Association>
            <Association Name="FK_Posts_Users">
              <End Role="Users" Type="XDbModel.Store.Users" Multiplicity="1" />
              <End Role="Posts" Type="XDbModel.Store.Posts" Multiplicity="*" />
              <ReferentialConstraint>
                <Principal Role="Users">
                  <PropertyRef Name="UserID" />
                </Principal>
                <Dependent Role="Posts">
                  <PropertyRef Name="PosterID" />
                </Dependent>
              </ReferentialConstraint>
            </Association>
            <Association Name="FK_ResourceEdges_Resources">
              <End Role="Resources" Type="XDbModel.Store.Resources" Multiplicity="1" />
              <End Role="ResourceEdges" Type="XDbModel.Store.ResourceEdges" Multiplicity="*" />
              <ReferentialConstraint>
                <Principal Role="Resources">
                  <PropertyRef Name="ResourceId" />
                </Principal>
                <Dependent Role="ResourceEdges">
                  <PropertyRef Name="ToResourceId" />
                </Dependent>
              </ReferentialConstraint>
            </Association>
            <Association Name="FK_ResourceEdges_Resources1">
              <End Role="Resources" Type="XDbModel.Store.Resources" Multiplicity="1" />
              <End Role="ResourceEdges" Type="XDbModel.Store.ResourceEdges" Multiplicity="*" />
              <ReferentialConstraint>
                <Principal Role="Resources">
                  <PropertyRef Name="ResourceId" />
                </Principal>
                <Dependent Role="ResourceEdges">
                  <PropertyRef Name="FromResourrceId" />
                </Dependent>
              </ReferentialConstraint>
            </Association>
            <Association Name="FK_ResourceNames_Resources">
              <End Role="Resources" Type="XDbModel.Store.Resources" Multiplicity="1">
                <OnDelete Action="Cascade" />
              </End>
              <End Role="ResourceNames" Type="XDbModel.Store.ResourceNames" Multiplicity="*" />
              <ReferentialConstraint>
                <Principal Role="Resources">
                  <PropertyRef Name="ResourceId" />
                </Principal>
                <Dependent Role="ResourceNames">
                  <PropertyRef Name="ResourceId" />
                </Dependent>
              </ReferentialConstraint>
            </Association>
            <Association Name="FK_Users_Locations">
              <End Role="Locations" Type="XDbModel.Store.Locations" Multiplicity="0..1">
                <OnDelete Action="Cascade" />
              </End>
              <End Role="Users" Type="XDbModel.Store.Users" Multiplicity="*" />
              <ReferentialConstraint>
                <Principal Role="Locations">
                  <PropertyRef Name="LocationId" />
                </Principal>
                <Dependent Role="Users">
                  <PropertyRef Name="LocationId" />
                </Dependent>
              </ReferentialConstraint>
            </Association>
            <Association Name="FK_Votes_Posts">
              <End Role="Posts" Type="XDbModel.Store.Posts" Multiplicity="1">
                <OnDelete Action="Cascade" />
              </End>
              <End Role="Votes" Type="XDbModel.Store.Votes" Multiplicity="*" />
              <ReferentialConstraint>
                <Principal Role="Posts">
                  <PropertyRef Name="PostId" />
                </Principal>
                <Dependent Role="Votes">
                  <PropertyRef Name="PostId" />
                </Dependent>
              </ReferentialConstraint>
            </Association>
          </Schema>
        </edmx:StorageModels>
        <!-- CSDL content -->
        <edmx:ConceptualModels>
          <Schema Namespace="XDbModel" Alias="Self" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
            <EntityContainer Name="XDbEntities" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
              <EntitySet Name="Bundles" EntityType="XDbModel.Bundle" />
              <EntitySet Name="CellProviders" EntityType="XDbModel.CellProvider" />
              <EntitySet Name="Comments" EntityType="XDbModel.Comment" />
              <EntitySet Name="LocationPoints" EntityType="XDbModel.LocationPoint" />
              <EntitySet Name="Locations" EntityType="XDbModel.Location" />
              <EntitySet Name="Offers" EntityType="XDbModel.Offer" />
              <EntitySet Name="PostMedias" EntityType="XDbModel.PostMedia" />
              <EntitySet Name="Posts" EntityType="XDbModel.Post" />
              <EntitySet Name="ResourceEdges" EntityType="XDbModel.ResourceEdge" />
              <EntitySet Name="ResourceNames" EntityType="XDbModel.ResourceName" />
              <EntitySet Name="Resources" EntityType="XDbModel.Resource" />
              <EntitySet Name="sysdiagrams" EntityType="XDbModel.sysdiagram" />
              <EntitySet Name="Users" EntityType="XDbModel.User" />
              <EntitySet Name="Votes" EntityType="XDbModel.Vote" />
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_Comments_Offers" Association="XDbModel.FK_Comments_Offers">
                <End Role="Offers" EntitySet="Offers" />
                <End Role="Comments" EntitySet="Comments" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_Comments_Users" Association="XDbModel.FK_Comments_Users">
                <End Role="Users" EntitySet="Users" />
                <End Role="Comments" EntitySet="Comments" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_LocationPoints_Locations" Association="XDbModel.FK_LocationPoints_Locations">
                <End Role="Locations" EntitySet="Locations" />
                <End Role="LocationPoints" EntitySet="LocationPoints" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_Posts_Locations" Association="XDbModel.FK_Posts_Locations">
                <End Role="Locations" EntitySet="Locations" />
                <End Role="Posts" EntitySet="Posts" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_Users_Locations" Association="XDbModel.FK_Users_Locations">
                <End Role="Locations" EntitySet="Locations" />
                <End Role="Users" EntitySet="Users" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_Posts_ResourceNames" Association="XDbModel.FK_Posts_ResourceNames">
                <End Role="ResourceNames" EntitySet="ResourceNames" />
                <End Role="Posts" EntitySet="Posts" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_Posts_Users" Association="XDbModel.FK_Posts_Users">
                <End Role="Users" EntitySet="Users" />
                <End Role="Posts" EntitySet="Posts" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_Votes_Posts" Association="XDbModel.FK_Votes_Posts">
                <End Role="Posts" EntitySet="Posts" />
                <End Role="Votes" EntitySet="Votes" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_ResourceEdges_Resources" Association="XDbModel.FK_ResourceEdges_Resources">
                <End Role="Resources" EntitySet="Resources" />
                <End Role="ResourceEdges" EntitySet="ResourceEdges" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_ResourceEdges_Resources1" Association="XDbModel.FK_ResourceEdges_Resources1">
                <End Role="Resources" EntitySet="Resources" />
                <End Role="ResourceEdges" EntitySet="ResourceEdges" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="FK_ResourceNames_Resources" Association="XDbModel.FK_ResourceNames_Resources">
                <End Role="Resources" EntitySet="Resources" />
                <End Role="ResourceNames" EntitySet="ResourceNames" />
              </AssociationSet>
              <AssociationSet Name="PostBundleJunction" Association="XDbModel.PostBundleJunction">
                <End Role="Bundles" EntitySet="Bundles" />
                <End Role="Posts" EntitySet="Posts" />
              </AssociationSet>
            </EntityContainer>
            <EntityType Name="Bundle">
              <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="BundleId" />
              </Key>
              <Property Name="BundleId" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
              <NavigationProperty Name="Posts" Relationship="XDbModel.PostBundleJunction" FromRole="Bundles" ToRole="Posts" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="CellProvider">
              <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="CellProviderID" />
              </Key>
              <Property Name="CellProviderID" Type="Guid" Nullable="false" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="Comment">
              <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="CommentID" />
```

Comment: Which version of entity-framework / VS2010(?) are you on?

Comment: VS2010 RC1, not sure the framework version.

Comment: SingleOrDefault method is Linq2Sql... Use FirstOrDefault in EF instead. Just an observation.

Comment: @Robert actually both these methods are present in BOTH L2S and EF.. The difference is their behaviour. If your query returns more than one object in the result set then FirstOrDefault will return the first one. SingleOrDefault will instead throw an exception!

Comment: @Artiom: Good point. I know that both are present in EF as well... But you've pointed out the obvious difference.

Comment: Just to be clear: SingleOrDefault is not supported in EF 3.5.  It is now supported in EF 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, it's actually very simple, once you think about it..
What you're trying to do it add the resource to the data context, even though this resource object was received from the database in the first place. So the error is not complaining about your child objects, but about your parent object! :)

Basically if you comment the first line in the SaveResource() method it should just work fine!
E.g.:

```
public void SaveResource(Resource resource)
{
    // context.AddToResources(resource); //Should also add children.
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Or just move the AddChildResource method to your DAL:

```
public void AddChildResource(int parentResourceId, Resource childResource)
{
    Resource parentResource = repository.GetResource(parentResourceId);

    ResourceEdge inEdge = new ResourceEdge();
    inEdge.ToResource = childResource;

    parentResource.ToEdges.Add(inEdge);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably it's complaining about the childResource not being in the added state.  You added it to the edge object that is in the added state.

Can you try flipping the way you set that association round:-

```
public void  AddChildResource(int parentResourceId, Resource childResource)
{
    Resource parentResource = repository.GetResource(parentResourceId);

    ResourceEdge inEdge = new ResourceEdge();
    // inEdge.ToResource = childResource;  <-- don't do this

    parentResource.ToEdges.Add(inEdge);
    childResource.FromEdges.Add(inEdge);  // try this instead

    repository.SaveResource(parentResource);
}
```

Comment: Hello, I get the same error both ways :(. At this point, I'm considering never to use EF for my other projects.

Comment: Were all of these objects loaded from the same object context?  How is your ObjectContext lifetime managed?

Comment: And can you post the EF/VS version number and EDMX file if possible too?

Comment: Not sure what the ObjectContext lifetime is. But from the code above in the Service "AddChildResource', The childResource entity parameter was created from code based on information gathered from the user. The parentResource comes straight from the repository database via the function GetResource(int) in the DAL.