# Code First TPT Inheritance - How can I supply the foreign key instead of EF creating the parent row for me?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a basic inheritance hierarchy like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentID {get; set;}

    public string SomeOtherProperty {get; set;}
};

public class Child : Parent
{
    public string SomeChildProperty {get; set;}
};
```

I have multiple child classes and I have an Auditor object that has an interface based on the Parent class that allows me to write to the database in a generic way, like this

```
public class Auditor
{
    public void WriteObject(Parent p)
    {
        using (MyDbContext context = new Context)
        {
            context.Parents.Add(p);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

So I can use Auditor like

```
auditor.WriteObject(new Child1());
auditor.WriteObject(new Child2());
```

etc, etc, and whenever I write a Child object, EF created the Parent row in the DB for me.

The problem I'm having is in some cases (maybe 10% of the time), I want to write a Child record to the DB and link it to an existing Parent row, i.e. I want to supply the foreign key.

I tried something like

```
Child1 child = new Child();
child1.ParentID = existingID;
auditor.WriteObject(child);
```

But EF ignored the foreign key I supplied and created a new Parent record for me.

Is there anyway to get EF to understand that, since the parent ID already exists on the Child object I'm trying to write, that it doesn't need to insert the parent row?

Comment: Why does Child inherit Parent? Shouldn't Child have a Parent property?

Comment: Hi Usr.  Yes, Child could have a Parent property but then that would be establishing a foreign key relationship, not an inheritance relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a little confused based on your description, but will try to answer the scenarios I think you might mean:

**Option 1**: I think this is what you are after: You are creating objects of the parent class. Later, you have more information and want to 'downcast' them to the appropriate subclass. This is not possible in this way with EF. Once the object is created as a specific type that is what it must remain. The option then in your case is the following:

1. Does this object already exist as (parentType)
2. Delete Object(ParentType)
3. Save object (ChildType)

See better worded explainations than I could give here:

[Add child to existing parent record in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618586/add-child-to-existing-parent-record-in-entity-framework)

[Downcasting with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266848/downcasting-with-entity-framework)

If this is what you are intending to do I would suggest that some part of the model being implemented should be reconsidered to avoid these situations.

**Option 2**: You have a list of child elements which belong as a group to a parent object (in this case of a super-type):

In these cases you can load the parent, add the child to the parent and then save (at the parent level):

```
Child1 child = new Child();
Parent p = _context.Parents.Find(search based on ID)
p.Children.Add(child);
auditor.WriteObject(p);
```

**UPDATE: Option 3**

Based on your comment of shared parent id: what you are talking about now is not a TPT implementation and you are breaking a rule here. In TPT you have a single ID which resides in the 'parent' table which is the primary key across all tables for each object. There should never be a case where two child objects (of any type) have the same primary key, and in all cases a childs primary key **IS** the parentID. Using less abstract terms might help remove the confusion: if the parent table is Animal and the child tables are Cat and Dog it becomes obvious that Cat and dog would not share a primary key (as they are different types. I think what you might be attempting to achieve is possibly the inverse: a Child should contain an instance of parent (using the terminology from your question).

To say this one more way, if parentID is the primary key it will only exist in one branch of the hierarchy of objects, and will only serve to pull together the chain of inheritance which makes up this object. For example if I have an hierarchy like

Animal->Dog->Poodle

and I create a new poodle with ID=1, I will only ever have one set of records with ID=1, and it will be one row in each of Animal, Dog and Poodle. (and all three of these records are for the same Poodle object),

Comment: Hi Matthew.  Option 2 is what I'm after.  I know that I could do what you suggested, however I'm hesitant to do so.  I'm trying to keep Parent generic, and allow applications to extend it via children however they want.  If I add a Children collection to Parent, Parent is no longer generic.

Comment: Your comment actually leads me to think you are still talking about option 1 (or maybe mixing the idea of the two). What your code leads me to think is that in some cases the parent object already exists and you are 'extending' it as a child-type object (trying to set the parent ID). In your case could Parent be an abstract class? If the intent is to allow someone to later load a parent object, extend it as a child type, adding details, and than re-saving it, you need to follow the approach in option 1.

Comment: You are right.... I typed too fast and meant to say Option 1.  I can't delete the database row corresponding to the Parent type instance, because that row could be the parent to other child types. Meaning the parent row was created by saving another child type, and I want to latch onto it with this child type.  Maybe my only option is to go back to a good old ADO.NET stored proc :)

Comment: I updated my answer - I don't think you need to abandon the fight yet, I just think you are missing that while you may have a TPT solution, you are currently trying to misuse it to accomplish this task. :)

Comment: Hi Matthew.  AFter reading your update and doing more work on my own I came to the same conclusion - I'm mis-using TPT inheritance here.  I re-worked my code to just use a standard one to many foreign key relationship.  Thanks for helping me work it through!